# How to write signature of custom GA functions? (Selection, Mutation, Crossover)

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

It is hard for me to find Documentation on **how to write signatures of my custom selection, mutation, crossover functions** for Genetic Algorithm.

I can't figure out how ga() functions works. (I know this exists: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/how-the-genetic-algorithm-works.html) ), but how these functions communicate, what they are expecting for inputs and for outputs?

**Q&A, More about my problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689104/ga-custom-integer-selection-with-roulette-wheel)**

This are my GA options:

```
options = gaoptimset(...
                      'PopulationSize',    10, ...
                      'Generations',       50, ...
                      'CrossoverFcn',      {'crossoverscattered'}, ...
                      'MutationFcn',       { @Mutation, 0.01 }, ...
                      'SelectionFcn',      { @RouletteWheelSelection }, ...
                      'UseParallel',       true, ...
                      'Display', 'iter' ...
                     );
```

My **GA** function:

```
lb = 1;  % Lower bound on x
ub = 3;  % Upper bound on x
nvars = 1;
x = ga(@GaFitness,nvars,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],[],options);
```

My **GaFitness** Fcn signature (for now):

```
function result  = GaFitness()
```

My **Mutation** function signature:

```
 function chromosome  = Mutation( chromosome )
```

My **Selection** function signature:

```
function selected_chromosome = RouletteWheelSelection( population )
```

If you need more info about my problem or more code, pls let me know.

This is Error I'm getting:

```
Error using GaFitness

Too many input arguments.

Error in createAnonymousFcn>@(x)fcn(x,FcnArgs{:}) (line 11)

fcn_handle = @(x) fcn(x,FcnArgs{:});

Error in makeState (line 47)

            firstMemberScore = FitnessFcn(state.Population(initScoreProvided+1,:));

Error in galincon (line 17)
state = makeState(GenomeLength,FitnessFcn,Iterate,output.problemtype,options);

Error in ga (line 374)
            [x,fval,exitFlag,output,population,scores] = galincon(FitnessFcn,nvars, ...

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied fitness function evaluation. GA cannot continue.
```

**Using Matlab 2016b.**

Comment: No input for `GaFitness()`?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to figure out what my input needs to be, also my output. 
I assume it will be a chromosome which is a set of rules for a fuzzy controller. 
This is my Q&A about my problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689104/ga-custom-integer-selection-with-roulette-wheel)

Comment: What's the function you want to optimize? `GaFitness()` takes a chromosome as input and returns a value, the higher values one get their chromosome selected for  `RouletteWheelSelection` tournament

Comment: @adam.Yes, I want to optimize `GaFitness()`, more precisely Fuzzy control rules inside `GaFitness`. So, I assume input will be a set of rules (chromosome, exp.: [`1,2,3,1,1..]` and based on that input, return a result of xy variable that was impacted of new fuzzy settings.

Comment: Perhaps [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42838593/3372061) could help you.

Comment: @Dev-iL thanks, I will give it a try today or tomorrow.

Comment: @Dev-iL I looked at your answer that you linked and basically if I understood right, inputs are irrelevant, but the output must be as documented. In ˙GaFitness˙ input will be chromosome, and output result I want to minimize. Could you help me with other functions? (Mutation/Selection) Where can I look at what they need for input/output? Some example maybe?