# GA stepGA - Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I'm writing **Custom GA functions in MATLAB** for mixed integer problem. More about my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689104/ga-custom-integer-selection-with-roulette-wheel) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759269/how-to-write-signature-of-custom-ga-functions-selection-mutation-crossover).

After Roulette Wheel **selection** is over, Matlab breaks with error:

```
 Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in stepGA (line 34)
xoverKids  = feval(options.CrossoverFcn, parents(1:(2 * nXoverKids)),options,GenomeLength,FitnessFcn,thisScore,thisPopulation,options.CrossoverFcnArgs{:});

Error in galincon (line 62)
        [score,population,state] = stepGA(score,population,options,state,GenomeLength,FitnessFcn);

Error in ga (line 374)
            [x,fval,exitFlag,output,population,scores] = galincon(FitnessFcn,nvars, ...
```

It breaks in stepGA.m at:

```
xoverKids  = feval(options.CrossoverFcn, parents(1:(2 * nXoverKids)),options,GenomeLength,FitnessFcn,thisScore,thisPopulation,options.CrossoverFcnArgs{:});
```

More precisely at `parents(1:(2 * nXoverKids))`.

**My variables** at that time:

```
nXoverKids = 7
nParents = 16
nEliteKids = 1
nMutateKids = 2
parents = 1 1
```

**My Roullete wheel selection:**

```
function parents = RouletteWheelSelection(expectation, nParents, options)
% ---------------------------------------------------------
% Roulette Wheel Selection Algorithm. A set of weights
% represents the probability of selection of each
% individual in a group of choices. It returns the chosen chromosome.
% ---------------------------------------------------------
  r1 = rand;
  r2 = rand;
  index1 = sum(r1 >= cumsum([0, expectation']));
  index2 = sum(r2 >= cumsum([0, expectation']));

  parents = [index1, index2];
end
```

From Matlab [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html)**:**

> The function returns parents, a row vector of length nParents
>   containing the indices of the parents that you select.

**Am I returning wrong** from Selection? And why are *nParents* set at **16**?

**My other options for GA:**

```
options = gaoptimset(...
                      'PopulationSize',    10, ...
                      'Generations',       50, ...
                      'InitialPopulation', population.chromosomes(1,:),...
                      'SelectionFcn',      @RouletteWheelSelection, ...
                      'CrossoverFcn',      @Crossover, ...
                      'MutationFcn',       @Mutation
                     );
lb = 1;  % Lower bound on x
ub = 3;  % Upper bound on x
nvars = 81;

rules = population.chromosomes(1, :);



 x = ga(@(x)GaFitness(rules, sim_obj, EV_input_time_first, EV_input_time_second, inpxpath, layxpath, Results),...
       nvars,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],[],options);
```

Also my **InitialPopulation** `population.chromosomes(1,:)` is *1x81 size*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - `RouletteWheelSelection` doesn't return parents with     2 individuals

- Assuming the population contains `10` individuals
- During `RouletteWheelSelection` you'll be asked to choose `nParents` out of the `10`, `5` for example

> Obviously `nParents` should not exceed `PopulationSize`
>
> You have set `nParents =  16` while `PopulationSize = 10`

- The correct word will be `nIndividuals` instead of `nParents`
- `expectation` means probability, a value comprised between 0 and 1, also called  `relative fitness`

```
expectation(individual_1) = fitness(individual_1)/sum(fitness(ALL_individuals));
```

**Illustrative example on `ga` parameters setting**

```
% lower bound
lb = -2;
% upper bound
ub = 2;

% Population size
individuals = 10;
% Fitness function
fitness = @(x) -x.^2;

% Given population, 10 individuals

pop = linspace(lb, ub, individuals);

% All Population individuals Fitness
pop_fitness = fitness(pop);

% All Population individuals relative Fitness 
rfit = pop_fitness./sum(pop_fitness);

% All Population individuals cumulative fitness, sum up to 1
cumulative_relative_fit = cumsum(rfit);

% Number of individuals to be selected out of 10
nparents = 5;
sel = zeros(1, nparents);

% Indices of individuals in population
index = 1:numel(pop);

% Roulette Wheel Selection starts here

for i = 1 : nparents
    rnd = rand;
if rnd <=  cumulative_relative_fit(1)
    % Selected the first individual 
    % if first Cumulative relative fitness is higher than
    % generated random number 
    sel(i) = 1;
else
     % Find indices where generated random number is higher than 
     % Cumulative relative fitness
     ind = rnd >=  cumulative_relative_fit;
     
     
     ALL_Indices_Above_Cum = index(ind);
     % Choose the one with the highest Cumulative relative fitness
     sel(i) = ALL_Indices_Above_Cum(end);
end

end
```

**Selected Individuals**

```
nParents = 5;
Population Size = 10;
sel = [4     9     1     7     1];
```

---

> **Change your custom selection function to this**

```
function parents = RouletteWheelSelection(expectation, nParents, 'ga')
% ---------------------------------------------------------
% Roulette Wheel Selection Algorithm. A set of weights
% represents the probability of selection of each
% individual in a group of choices. It returns the chosen chromosome.
% ---------------------------------------------------------
    % Population individuals indices
    index = 1 : numel(expectation);
    
    % Indices of individuals to be selected 
    parents = zeros(1, nParents);

    % Cumulative relative fitness, the last one is 1
    cumulative_relative_fit = cumsum(expectation); 
    
    
    for i = 1:  nParents
        rnd = rand;
        % Selected the first individual 
        % if first Cumulative relative fitness is higher than
        % generated random number 
        
        if rnd <=  cumulative_relative_fit(1)
            parents(i) = 1;
        else
             % Find indices where generated random number is higher than 
             % Cumulative relative fitness
             ind = rnd >=  cumulative_relative_fit;

             ALL_Indices_Above_Cum = index(ind);
             % Choose the one with the highest Cumulative relative fitness            
             parents(i) = ALL_Indices_Above_Cum(end);
        end
    end
 
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot, I fixed my selection and mutation. Now ga is running. Can you give me a hand with restrictions on ga? I'm working only with integers in chromosomes, from 1 to 3, but ga is generating from-10 to 10. 
My ga `ga(@(rules) gafitness(rules), nvars,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[], options);`  where lb is 1 and ub is 3.   Do I need to set `IntCon` and how? @Adam

Comment: If I set `IntCon` to `1:1:nvars`, I'm getting values between -10k and +10k in integers. But I set my bound to 1-3 ?

Comment: @codemonkey   Alright, it's better you make a new post showing me the parameters setting as well as the fitness function. You don't need to show me exactly your fitness function but need something similar.

Comment: thanks I figure it out. The thing is, if I set IntConstraint on all gens, it cannot use my custom Crossover, Mutation or Selection. And my bounds were wrong, I didn't set an array of bounds for every gen, instead, I set scalar value. Which is wrong.  Matlab documentation is a bit confusing, for me.

Comment: You probably need to write GA algorithm from scratch by yourself, then it'll be quite easy to understand the matlab build-in version. If you wan to know more check this github link of mine , but I wrote the code in python with lot of comments https://github.com/zoumson/Evolutionary_Computation.git